# addEventListener function fails to redirect on another page

Tags: javascript, html

does anyone know why the function does not work?
I tried to make a function so when a user clicks on the Sign up, it should open another page.

------JS------
[image]
------HTML------

[image]

I tried to make a function so when a user clicks on the Sign up, it should open another page.

when I click on the `Sign up` it should redirect me to http://google.com

Comment: Please, don't use images. Just paste the original code with proper formatting. It's easier for anyone to replicate and test.

Comment: I am sorry, I'll use the original code from now on. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The most probable cause is not preventing the default link behaviour.

To do that, just use the `preventDefault()` method:

```js
btn.addEventListener("click", function(event){
  event.preventDefault(); // <= Prevent default behavior, relinking to the same page due to href=""
  window.location.href = "https://google.com"; // <= Do our custom redirecting here safely
});
```

Always check the browser console for errors and [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) issues